# How to copy files to all the user profiles under C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local (Using batch file)

Tags: batch-file, local, appdata

I want to copy iTunesPrefs.xml file for all the users, who have ever logged on to the PC, under the above mentioned location (for iTunes installation). If I run the batch file as a current user, I can only write to my AppData Folder. Also, if I do copy the file to "Default" User; only the new staff who are logging in will get the required settings. I have a system account, which can log onto all the User folders. So, I want it to be copied across all the currently existing profiles. For e.g for following users:

1. Charlie : C:\Users\Charlie\AppData\Local
2. Adam : C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Local
3. Gregg : C:\Users\Gregg\AppData\Local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work. Assuming you have admin rights to the other user folders. Its very down and dirty, and will throw an error if the `appdata\local\` directory does not exist.

When you run this in the `C:\users\` directory, it attempts to do a copy on every profile in the `C:\users\ directory`.

```
FOR /d %G in ("*") DO copy C:\temp\iTunesPrefs.xml C:\users\%G\appdata\local\
```

Comment: I have a co-worker with an AutoIT script that does something very similar.  But he has built a GUI that gives the user control over some things.  I will see if he wouldn't mind publishing to GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f %a in ('dir c:\users /b') do xcopy C:\temp\test123.txt c:\users\%a\appdata\local
```

Comment: Please dont post code only answer, try to add some context of how this will solve the problem in question.